# zipping two lists together in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function called zip that accepts two lists as parameters and and returns a single list whose elements are taken alternatively from the original lists

ex. (zip '(a b c) '(x y z)) should evaluate to (a x b y c z)

Comment: using recursion, without importing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skeleton solution:

```
(define (zip l1 l2)
  (cond ((null? l1) l2)
        ((null? l2) l1)
        (else (cons ??? (cons ??? (zip ??? ???))))))
```

Fill in the `???` yourself. :-)